# Segunda via para bancos em PHP

Tags: php

Gostaria de saber se alguém já desenvolveu um código para geração de segunda via do banco ITAU, da forma que é feito no site, passando apenas o código do boleto.

Vi algumas API, mais vi que existe a necessidade de passar todos os dados, e não somente o número do boleto.

Se alguém puder ajudar.

Obrigado.

Comment: Bom, o código do boleto é gerado a partir dos dados do banco, da compra, e dados do cliente, como você pretende fazer um boleto usando somente o código? Não entendi. A propósito, se você já tem o código, ele deve ter sido gerado de alguma forma, correto? Talvez a api que o gerou responda sua pergunta. A 2ª via é uma cópia exata da primeira.

Comment: O primeiro boleto é gerado diretamente pelo site do banco, já a segunda via, com recalculo é regerado também pelo site apenas com a agencia, código do beneficiário e o nosso numero. Já os módulos de boletos disponíveis na web, pedem todos os dados do boleto.

Comment: Então você só precisa extrair estes dados e montar a tela do boleto.